# previousSibling shows two different things in console

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to use a button to move an li in a ul up the list. I am using the console to track certain variables to see if my code is functioning properly. I found something very curious while watching the console.

When I click on the up arrow for an item in the list, the variable itemBefore shows "#text" (object) in the console. Also, the list item doesn't move like it's supposed to. It stays put.

Now I click the button on the same list item again the console instead shows an li and the list item does indeed move up. It does this for every list item that is not the first (because that will execute another subset of code in the if statement).

I want to know why the exact same onclick does two different things and how to stop it from failing the first time.

```
<ul id="incomplete-tasks">
    <li>
        <button class="arrow up">&#8593;</button>
        <button class="arrow down">&#8595;</button>
        <label>Item 1</label>
        <input type="text">
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="arrow up">&#8593;</button>
        <button class="arrow down">&#8595;</button>
        <label>Item 2</label>
        <input type="text">
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="arrow up">&#8593;</button>
        <button class="arrow down">&#8595;</button>
        <label>Item 3</label>
        <input type="text">
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var moveUp = function() {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    var ul = listItem.parentNode;
    var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var arr = [].slice.call(items);
    var position = arr.indexOf(listItem);
    console.log(position);
    if (position < 1) {
        var removedChild = ul.removeChild(listItem);
        ul.appendChild(removedChild);
    } else {
        var itemBefore = listItem.previousSibling;
        console.log(itemBefore);
        var removedChild = ul.removeChild(listItem);
        ul.insertBefore(removedChild, itemBefore);
    }
};
```

If you want/need to look at the whole code to demonstrate the error, the jsfiddle is linked:

https://jsfiddle.net/09yyfxae/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're capturing whitespace. If you edit your markup to remove it, e.g.

```
<ul id="incomplete-tasks"><li>
    <button class="arrow up">&#8593;</button>
    <button class="arrow down">&#8595;</button>
    <label>Item 1</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li><li>
    <button class="arrow up">&#8593;</button>
    <button class="arrow down">&#8595;</button>
    <label>Item 2</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
<button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li><li>
    <button class="arrow up">&#8593;</button>
    <button class="arrow down">&#8595;</button>
    <label>Item 3</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you will get correct item every time: https://jsfiddle.net/09yyfxae/1/

Alternatively (and preferably) just skip the whitespace in code if you encounter it and perform another sibling lookup, e.g.:

```
var itemBefore = listItem.previousSibling;
while (itemBefore.nodeName == '#text') itemBefore = itemBefore.previousSibling;
```

Comment: How do I skip whitespace in code? Thinking about it, I could run a while loop, as long as the variable is "whitespace" do another sibling lookup. But how do I represent whitespace in JavaScript?

Comment: @JohnCoolidge You can simple watch for text node, something along the lines:
 `while (itemBefore.nodeName == '#text') itemBefore = itemBefore.previousSibling;` tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/09yyfxae/3/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @JohnCoolidge glad it worked for you. I've included that code in the answer to have complete example. Please mark it as answered if it performs as desired.

Answer (score 0):

That’s because the whitespace between your closing `</li>` and next opening `<li>` tags creates text nodes (hence the first debug output saying `#text`).

So on the first click, you are moving your `li` before the text node that precedes it – and only on the next click do you actually move it before the next `li`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling

Comment: Ah, after looking through the notes on the MDN for previousSibling, it says exactly that. The examples they used didn't have siblings on the next line, thus, no white space. Is there a property like previous sibling that disregards white space, or an I just stuck with some cluttered HTML?